# Vue js fetch data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, vuex

I have a app VUE JS I face a problem in the navigations bar the navigations bar containt a image user if i click in the image user profile take me to profile but if i navigate in to another user profile and  i want to go in my profile the path change but the data not load to the login user but if i reload the page the data fetch to the login user i want if i click in the user image profile in the navigation load data.

this method handled the click user image profile in the navigations component, I import the CoachDetails method but not fetching the data

```
<script>
import CoachDetails from "../../views/coaches/CoachDetails.vue";
export default {
  methods: {
    mainUserProfile() {
      this.$router.replace(`/coaches/${this.userId}`);
      if (CoachDetails.methods && CoachDetails.methods.loadCoachesDtails) {
        CoachDetails.methods.loadCoachesDtails();
      }
    },
 {
};
</script>
```

this script is the CoachDetails component script handled the fetch data from data base

```
<script>
export default {
  props: ["id"],
  methods: {
    async loadCoachesDtails(refresh = true) {
      this.isLoading = true;
      console.log("before");
      try {
        await this.$store.dispatch("coaches/loadCoachData", {
          importRefresh: refresh,
        });

        console.log("after");

        this.theSelectedCoach = this.$store.getters["coaches/coaches"].find(
          (coach) => coach.id === this.id
        );

        this.error = null;
      } catch (err) {
        this.error = err || "Something went worng!!";
      } finally {
        this.isLoading = false;
      }
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.loadCoachesDtails();
  },
};
```

i try to fetch data in the mainUserProfile method but not working as expect and i try to dispatch the load data method from the store actions and not workin also

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```js
<template>
    <CoachDetails ref="CoachDetails" v-show="false" />
</template>
<script>
import CoachDetails from "../../views/coaches/CoachDetails.vue";
export default {
    methods: {
        mainUserProfile() {
            // some ....
            if (this?.$refs['CoachDetails']?.loadCoachesDtails) {
                this.$refs['CoachDetails'].loadCoachesDtails();
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).